# Laravel, Angular 2 , Inject the Service, EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of null

Tags: laravel, service, angular, inject

I want use angular 2 with laravel 5.1, So I use 'elixir-typescript' to compile the typescript. The file structure like this:

```
laravel\resources\assets\typescript
some .ts file

laravel\public\js
the js file
```

When I try the Tour of Heroes tutorial, everything is ok until  Inject the Service.

I find every solution for this problem, but not work.

1.I have import the files;

2.`typings install es6-promise` , it says : (No dependencies)

3.Not only myself service but also the angular service. But I can 'new' a service.

Can someone give me some solutions? Thanks so much.

[the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppDEw.png)
[the files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpYiM.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to import and provide the service.

Comment: Sorry for my poor English. I have to import and provide the service.  import { HeroService } from './hero.service'; and providers: [HeroService]

Comment: If you provide the code, then I might be able to provide a more detailed answer. Ideally a Plunker that allows to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much. The [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/VKbDYksmazIbUfsiAlW8?p=catalogue) is here.It's very simple demo. And I have add a new pic of the files. The elixir-typescript translator the ts file complete.

Comment: Working Plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/fIrTfshs9yQC7V2Le0gS?p=preview No idea what could cause the problem.

Comment: Thanks.  It's look like some bugs of the [elixir-typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/elixir-typescript).